# Magento group pricing - how to change display of "old price" - "new price"

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create a site that has multiple levels of pricing.  I'm currently trying to wrap my head around how magento displays group pricing.

I see the function getHtmlprice() displays the following when a user is logged in, and has a group price applied to them.

Old price: $79.95
Now only: $51.25

I would like to be able to just have the price update (based on customer group), with no additional text/pricing.

Can anyone please advise me how to do this or point me towards a plugin that would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try $_product->getFinalPrice(); please!

Comment: Awesome thanks, that lead me in the right direction.  I replaced getHtmlprice() with: echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice());